# Prove that set contains least element.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A\not=\emptyset ,A\subset \mathbb{Z}$ and if $(\exists d\in \mathbb{Z})(\forall a\in A):d\le a$ then set A contains least element. How do I prove this? I understand I can use WOP principle. What I wrote down to notebook but I don't understand is:

> $B:=${$n \in \mathbb{Z}:\exists a\in A:n=a-d+1$}$\subset\mathbb{N}. $ Then from WOP there exists $min B$, where $minA=minB+d-1$.

So for the purpose of proof I created another subset $B \subset \mathbb{N}$ for using WOP. But it is not clear to me what $n=a-d+1$ is.

Comment: You probably mean $A \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: Also, you probably mean $\exists a \in A$ in the definition of $B$.

Comment: yes, I corrected the mistakes, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Did you mean $n = a + d + 1$?

Comment: no, in my notes it is as above in my question.

Comment: Ah yes that's correct, I was confused :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is, for each $a \in A$, writing down the number $n = a - d + 1$, and forming a set $B$ out of all the numbers $n$ that can be obtained this way.

This is because the criterion for a number $n$ to be an element of the set $B$ is that *there exists* a number $a$ in $A$ for which $n = a - d + 1$.

Edit:

In order to understand the above proof, you need to understand why it works for *any* set $A$ satisfying the hypothesis (that there exists a number $d$ which is $\leq$ all elements of $A$). However, to understand the relation between $B$ and $A$, it might be helpful to take an example of a particular $A$. So let's assume, for instance, that
$$A = \{ -8, -6, -4, \ldots \}.$$
Then there does exist a number $d$ which is $\leq a$ for all elements $a \in A$. We can choose $d = -8$, since there is in fact no element of $A$ smaller than $-8$. (We could also have chosen $d = -9, -11, -20,$ etc., but for our example we will take $d = -8$.)

How can we recognize if a number $n$ belongs to $B$ or not? Saying that $n$ is in the set $B$ means that it can be written as 
$$n = a - d + 1 = a - (-8) + 1$$
for some $a \in A$. We can be certain that any such number $n$ will be a natural number, because all numbers $a \in A$ are $\geq -8$, so we must have $a - (-8) \geq 0$, so $n = a - (-8) + 1 \geq 1$. And indeed, this is what we are about to see when we form the set $B$ now.

The set $B$ consists of all numbers $a - (-8) + 1 = a + 9$, where $a$ is an element of $A$. For example, taking $a = -8$, we see that $n = - 8 + 9 = 1 \in B$. Taking $a = -6$, we find $n = -6 + 9 = 3 \in B$. And so on, for all elements of $A$. Thus the set $B$ is given by
$$B = \{1, 3, 5, \ldots \}.$$
In our example, you can see that all the elements of $B$ are natural numbers.

Now your job will be to understand why if, instead of choosing the particular set $A$ that we did, we had allowed $A$ to be *any* set bounded below by the number $d$, this process would still have resulted in a set $B$ that was contained in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: But what are these numbers $a,d$?. How do they ensure that $B\subset \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The number $d$ is the number whose existence is assumed in the hypothesis of your theorem. But $a$ is not a single number; $a$ represents any element of $A$. For each choice of $a$ in $A$, you get a corresponding $n$.

Comment: Lets say I choose number $-5\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $-5=a-d+1 \subset \mathbb{N}$  Then a is what I am looking for? I am sorry I am so confused...

Comment: I've edited my answer to try to clarify.

Comment: Wow, thank you for very detailed answer, once I understood choosing set B the rest became clear I think.

Answer (score 1):

If $d > 0$, then $A$ is a set of positive integers and by WOP there exists a least element.

If $d \leq 0$, the idea is to "translate" $A$ by $-d+1$ in order to obtain a set $B$ containing positive integers. You need to do this because, in the worst case where $d \in A$ (say $d = -7$), after translating by $-d+1$ (i.e. by $8$ in the example), $d$ gets mapped to $1$ in $B$ and every other element in $A$ gets mapped to some integer $n \geq 1$ in $B$.

Then apply WOP to $B$ and note that $minA = minB + d - 1$. That is true because to get $minA$, all you need to do is to translate $minB$ by $-(-d+1) = d - 1$.